# interval (or pgfkeys) package: Undefined control sequence

Tags: pgfkeys

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{interval}
\begin{document}
$\interval{0}{5}$
\end{document}
```

I get the following in the log file

```
...

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interval/interval.sty
Package: interval 2019/03/06 v0.4

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks14
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks15

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities
/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks16
)))
c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/interval/interval.sty:56: Undefined
control sequence.
\pgfkeyssetevalue ...emptoks =\pgfutil@scantokens 
                                              \expandafter {\expandafter...
l.56 }

...
```

The output seems correct.

Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

your example worked in a tl2019 updated last week but fails after the last  pgf  update.

use

```
\usepackage{pgf,interval}
```

to make sure all parts of pgf get loaded (I think I saw this earlier reported so presumably the original version will work again after another pgf update)

Comment: actually I was thinking of https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/652#event-2264805008 but that's marked as fixed...

Comment: The bug has been introduced in pgf 3.1.2, but should be fixed in the sources. The pgf 3.1.2 was in texlive some weeks ago, then texlive rolled back to pgf 3.1.1, and now has reinstalled pgf 3.1.2 yesterday (perhaps by accident).